# Is Heretic 2 anyway connected to the Hexen series?

Tags: heretic-series, hexen-series

I know that Hexen is a sequel to Heretic and both had sequels, but is Heretic 2 anyway connected to Hexen or Hexen 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, from a storyline perspective, *Heretic 2* is essentially standalone. The other three games, *Heretic*, *Hexen*, and *Hexen 2* make up a trilogy based on the main antagonists.

In *Heretic*, the main character (an unnamed elf) fights against one of the three  Serpent Riders to liberate his world. In *Hexen* and *Hexen 2*, there is a different **protagonist**, each fighting one of the other Serpent Riders to liberate another world from their rule.

Thus, the *Hexen* games aren't really "sequels" to *Heretic*, but more like "parallel stories". They have the common theme of fighting the Serpent Riders, but otherwise, the main characters are unconnected.

*Heretic 2* **is** a direct sequel to *Heretic*. The main character returns (and we find out his name), fighting against a completely different disaster that has nothing to do with the Serpent Riders. Thus, it has nothing to link it to either *Hexen* game.

Comment: While I find your answer very informative, I find your "No" wrong. By your own post,  you can see Heretic 2 is related to Hexen, much like The Hobbit is related to Lord of the Rings.

Comment: I guess that depends on what you mean by "related". They take place in the same general universe, but on different planets, with different protagonists, different antagonists, and wholly separate story lines that have nothing to do with each other.